# Mix or separate apps in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

I have a bit complex project with todos, calendars, authentication, photos etc. in Django.

Should I separate the functionalities in apps or is it okay to mix it altogether. I think it's good to separate things but when all the apps are connected it's probably better to mix them?

When they are separated I'll also have problems with the urls. I will include all urls related to the auth with `url(r'^users/', include('myproject.apps.user.urls'))` but if I want my login url to be `/login` instead of `/users/login` it will become a bit messy.

I think the admin "tells me" to separate apps so each model can be listed in grouped sections.

I have tried searching for good practice on this problem but I couldn't find good explanations or arguments so I'm hoping to get some pros and cons here :-)

Thank you.

Comment: The point of modularization isn't that you can avoid it when they belong together on a bigger scale. You should still separate modules, as if they don't belong together so to speak.

Comment: Even if your applications have relationships, you still want to separate them. Keeping concerns separate will lead to an overall cleaner architecture of your project.